# Batch update of the Apps Script of a set of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a large set of Google Sheets which have exactly the same Apps Scripts code (several gs files in each Sheet).

Is it possible to update the code of these Sheets with a batch update, instead of opening each Sheet and pasting the new code in each gs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately, you can't update `scripts` by using a `script`.

You can write your master `code` somewhere and then duplicate the `spreadsheet` file so all of them will have the same code.

A better approach would be to create your own [Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) which will contain the full code and all the other spreadsheets will import this library. So you only need to update the code in one place.

Comment: "You can write your master code somewhere and then duplicate the spreadsheet file" => This is what I initially did but now I have to adapt the code of the master/template as well as all the Sheets derived from this template... The Library approach seems very interesting! One question: I use `PropertiesService` setters and getters in each sheet. Will using a Library share a value set in one Sheet with the other Sheets depending on the Library? (which I don't want: each sheet should hold values linked to the user)

Comment: I guess the answer to my last question is here in the doc: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#resource_scoping

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes exactly!

Comment: @RenaudTarnec here is a very informative YouTube video on how to create a library and then share it to other scripts. https://youtu.be/agWFuUMR6Vc